# PHP: How to organise queries and tables to generate HTML selection box

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel, database-design

I am attempting to create a drop down selection box for various attributes of a product which the user would select on a product page, such as weight or flavour or colour. My database for the products is currently as follows:

```
products(id,productname,productprice)

productattributes(id,productid,attributename,value)
```

I'm using Laravel. So far in my controller I have:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $product = DB::table('products')->where('slug', $id)->take(1)->get();
    $prodid = DB::table('products')->where('slug', $id)->pluck('id');
    $prodattr = DB::table('productattributes')->where('prodid', $prodid)->get();
    return View::make('product/singleproduct', ['product' => $product, 'prodattr' => $prodattr]);
}
```

And in the view I have:

```
@foreach ($prodattr as $prodattribute)

{{ $attrname = $prodattribute->attributename }}
{{ $attrvalue = $prodattribute->value }}

@endforeach
```

This gives me the output:

```
Flavour Unflavoured 
Flavour Strawberry 
Weight 1kg
```

So I have the data I need, but my problem is how to get this into a select box for each attribute. I won't always know what the attribute names will be (colour may be added, for example) or how many there will be, so I don't want to hard code 'Flavour' etc in. I essentially want to generate HTML like this:

```
<select name="flavour">
<option value="Unflavoured">Unflavoured</option>
<option value="Strawberry">Strawberry</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="weight">
<option value="1kg">1kg</option>
</select>
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm thinking a loop within the loop, or maybe my table layout is less than ideal? I thought about adding another query within the foreach loop, but this seems counterproductive as I think I have all the data I need. I also wondered if it would be possible to combine or merge the arrays somehow? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a third table in order to seperate custom attributes and available values for each attributes.

Example of structure I would use:

```
products(id, name, price)

product_meta_name(id, name)

product_meta_value(id, product_meta_name_id, product_id, value)
```